# MQ QDepth without knowing the queueManagerName

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am trying to check statistics on remote queues, however I need to connect without using the queueManagerName. I know it is possible however I have not been able to find an example or to get my code working?

```
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
    properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, host);
    properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);

    MQQueueManager qmgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, properties);

    try
    {
        var queueDepth = qmgr.AccessQueue(userQueue,
                                          MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF +
                                          MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING +
                                          MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE).CurrentDepth;

        var maxDepth = qmgr.AccessQueue(userQueue,
                          MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF +
                          MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING +
                          MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE).MaximumDepth;

        if (qmgr.IsOpen)
            qmgr.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(queueDepth);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (qmgr.IsOpen)
            qmgr.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code works perfectly fine for me and prints the queue depth correctly. I just changed this line:

```
MQQueueManager qmgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, properties);
```

to, just passing "" (blank) as queue manager name as your requirement was not to use queue manager name.

```
MQQueueManager qmgr = new MQQueueManager("", properties);
```